# r - Call multiple consecutive dataframes from global environment

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple df in the global environment that follow this pattern

```
dfA.1
dfA.2
.
.
.
dfA.n
```

and

```
dfB.1
dfB.2
.
.
.
dfB.n
```

I need to apply a function to each pair of dfA and dfB:

```
repeat {
  A <- dfA.n
  B <- dfB.n
  
  
  command(A, B), verbose = TRUE))
  }
```

How do I create a loop to call the df pairs one by one so that the command applies to each pair of df (e.g. dfA.1 dfB.1) and then move on to the next?

Thank you for your help. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ls` with `pattern` to get all the objects from global environment that follow a specific pattern. Use `mget` to get them in a list and with `Map` you can apply a function to each pair of variables.

```
Map(function(A, B) {apply the function here}, mget(ls(pattern = 'dfA')), 
                                              mget(ls(pattern = 'dfB')))
```